# Securing AngularJS Source Code

Tags: angularjs, minify, uglifyjs

Since Minify and Uglify can be easily reverse engineered, how then can source code of AngularJS apps really be secured so a developer cannot so easily copy and reuse code I sweat over for months?

Comment: If you don't want to share your code why should we sweat for a few minutes in order to help you? ;) If others copy your code it shouldn't really bother you tbh.

Comment: you can't, other than by not letting anyone use it.

Comment: it's a bit ironic that your code is built on top of an open source library someone else slaved over and shared with you for free

Comment: There's a gap between RE and actual code theft. Usually obfuscation and server side for sensible parts are more than enough, but be careful, they can offend open-source bigots.

Comment: javascript is opensource

Answer (score 3):

**You can't.**

**Any** client-side functionality can be (usually easily) reverse engineered and reused.

You secure your code by applying appropriate Terms & Conditions to the use of your application.

Comment: This is just another reason why we stick with developing web apps in Java server side frameworks like Wicket that give you all the dynamic HTML5, AJAX, partial updating of page components and model/view based architecture that Angular provides but without the 'hey people with no respect for IP laws, here's the source code of our entire UI' aspect of Angular. Plus by sticking with Java we don't have to throw away type safety and proper support for the object oriented paradigm which is essential if you want to developer your apps on the DRY principle.